# Can we execute msbuild command from sql agent job??If Yes then how?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I want to execute msbuild command from sql agent job?If yes kindly explain and If no then Why??

Comment: Yes, *just* like any other command line - you provide the full path or create a cmd that sets all required environment variables. *Why* do that though? SQL Server Agent isn't meant to build projects

Comment: You can run any external command using `xp_cmdshell`

Comment: I'm willing to bet a sizeable amount of money that whatever problem you are solving with this is either the wrong problem to solve, or the right problem being solved the wrong way. In particular, if you want to use information in the database as a trigger to a build system, a much saner solution is to either poll, or have a DML trigger that inserts an event in a Service Broker queue for an external service to pick up, or even a PowerShell job step that calls a web service. Directly invoking a build from SQL Server is just asking for lots of hard to diagnose trouble.

Comment: Can you please provide working example on how to perform it????